# How to use beginBitmapFill?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to draw a bitmap in flex,the original bitmap is

[image]

but, actually it show up in the app looks like

[image]

here is the code:

```
this.component.graphics.beginBitmapFill(leakBitmapData);
this.component.graphics.drawRect(leakPoint.x-halfWidth,leakPoint.y-halfHeight,leakBitmapData.width,leakBitmapData.height);
this.component.graphics.endFill();
```

only when I draw the rect at (0,0),it looks right.
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to draw something outside the origin, you will need to do a matrix translation on the BitmapData. Something like this:

```
var px:int = leakPoint.x - halfWidth;
var py:int = leakPoint.y - halfHeight;
var translationMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix;
translationMatrix.tx = px;
translationMatrix.ty = py;

this.component.graphics.beginBitmapFill(leakBitmapData, translationMatrix);
this.component.graphics.drawRect(px, py, leakBitmapData.width, leakBitmapData.height);
this.component.graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: I just solved the problem by myself.But you are right!That is the correct answer.

Comment: Oops. I never noticed you already figured it out. Well, just an FYI I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that "leakBitmapData" is a bitmapdata which is generated by code or loaded in the application.

```
this.component.graphics.beginBitmapFill(leakBitmapData, null, true, false);
this.component.graphics.drawRect(0,0, leakBitmapData.width, leakBitmapData.height);
this.component.graphics.endFill();

this.component.x = -(leakBitmapData.width/2);
this.component.y = -(leakBitmapData.height/2);
```

Comment: I have solved the problem,I need to do a matrix transform.But thank you all the same.